# Time interval to update battery infomation in Android-based phone

Tags: android, batterymanager

How long will it take for Android OS to update battery information ? (for example file in "/sys/class/power_supply/battery/current_now")

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a BroadcastReceiver for the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.

For more information see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED